# How can I use rsync in scalable Openshift application?

Tags: synchronization, openshift, rsync

Now Openshift doesn't have any synchronization mechanizm between gears in scalable application. I know about using shared database but it is not the option for my case.

I need some folder in OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR to be synchronized at some events. I thought that I can use rsync for the purpose, and as it is stated here it is possible.

https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/easy-way-to-move-files-between-my-gears

But I wasn't managed to do this. I generated ssh keys on 1st gear, added them using web control panel. 
And how can I spesify that I want to copy file into remote $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR. But even if I replace $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR with remote value of variable it won't work.

```
[tomcb-chicout.rhcloud.com data]\> rsync -i /var/lib/openshift/53e0d7304382ecb3
b70000c4/app-root/data/.ssh/rsync -avzhe /var/lib/openshift/53e0d7304382ecb3b70
000c4/app-root/data/test 53e0d7b4e0b8cd7a1f000069@10.147.167.151:/var/lib/opens
hift/53e0d7b4e0b8cd7a1f000069/app-root/data/


rsync: Failed to exec /var/lib/openshift/53e0d7304382ecb3b70000c4/app-root/data/
test: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(84) [sender=3.0.6]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=
3.0.6]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
[tomcb-chicout.rhcloud.com data]\> REMOTE_DATA=$(ssh 53e0d7b4e0b8cd7a1f000069@53e0d7b4e0b8cd7a1f000069-chicout.rhcloud.com 'echo $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR')
[tomcb-chicout.rhcloud.com data]\> rsync -avzhe ssh /var/lib/openshift/53e0d730
4382ecb3b70000c4/app-root/data/test 53e0d7b4e0b8cd7a1f000069@53e0d7b4e0b8cd7a1f
000069-chicout.rhcloud.com:/$REMOTE_DATA
sending incremental file list</code>

sent 82 bytes  received 12 bytes  188.00 bytes/sec
total size is 12  speedup is 0.13</code>
```